# Append a div with a form to an existing div using appendto

Tags: jquery

I am having some luck when i try appending some text to an existing div using

```
$("<div class='form-holder'>Append a form here</div>").appendTo('.container');
```

but everything goes south from there when i try

```
$(document).ready
(
function()
{
//$("<div class='form-holder'>Append a form here</div>").appendTo('.container');
$("<div class='form-holder'>"
"<form name="input" action="#" method="get">"
"<label>Slider Title:</label> <input type="text" name="slider_title" /><br/><br/>"
"<label>Slider Description:</label> <input type="text" name="slider_description" /><br/><br/>"
"<input type="submit" value="New Slider" />"
"<input type="submit" value="Update Slider" />"
"</form>"
"</div>").appendTo('.container');
}
);
```

You can see the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/F7YAe/

Comment: Are these just strings on seperate lines? You have to concatenate them together with +. That, plus you're trying to nest " inside ". Try ' inside " like "<input type='submit'...

Comment: notice the syntax highlighting here on SO. Your HTML cannot contain a `"` since the htmls live in the PHP world within a set of quotes.

Comment: @n8wrl they are separate lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replace your `"` with `'` and using the string concatenation operator `+`

Notice how my code is colored correctly, while yours is not. You cannot use that same type of quotes in JS and the HTML that lives within JS.

```
        $("<div class='form-holder'>" +
        "<form name='input' action='#' method='get'>" +
        "<label>Slider Title:</label> <input type='text' name='slider_title' /><br/><br/>" +
        "<label>Slider Description:</label> <input type='text' name='slider_description' /><br/><br/>" +
        "<input type='submit' value='New Slider' />" +
        "<input type='submit' value='Update Slider' />" +
        "</form>" +
        "</div>").appendTo('.container');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you aren't writing proper JavaScript.  You are splitting the string without using `+` between the lines.  Couple that with mixing single and double quotes, and you running into major issues.

```
$('<div class="form-holder">'+
'<form name="input" action="#" method="get">'+
'<label>Slider Title:</label> <input type="text" name="slider_title" /><br/><br/>'+
'<label>Slider Description:</label> <input type="text" name="slider_description" /><br/><br/>'+
'<input type="submit" value="New Slider" />'+
'<input type="submit" value="Update Slider" />'+
'</form>'+
'</div>').appendTo('.container');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F7YAe/9/

Comment: Hey, I started on my answer before you posted yours =)

Comment: Having an awkward moment choosing whose answer to accept since they both work.

Comment: @flapjack Just accept whichever one you want and upvote any that are helpful =)

Comment: @saluce I know. Just joshin. +1

Answer (score 1):

you have problem with your string you need escape quotations and + for concatenation or write your string in single line.

Answer (score 1):

Here a working exmaple !

http://jsfiddle.net/F7YAe/10/

```
$(document).ready(

function() {
    //$("<div class='form-holder'>Append a form here</div>").appendTo('.container');
    $("<div class='form-holder'><form name='input' action='#' method='get'><label>Slider Title:</label> <input type='text' name='slider_title' /><br/><br/><label>Slider Description:</label> <input type='text' name='slider_description'/><br/><br/><input type='submit' value='New Slider' /><input type='submit' value='Update Slider' /></form></div>").appendTo('.container');
});​
```

Comment: I can't think of any situation where the JS/HTML should be formatted like that. It's virtually unreadable.